# How do I generate an array that can contain all natural numbers that are greater than zero?

Tags: c, arrays

Natural numbers are the set of positive integers, which ranges from 1 to infinity excluding fractional part. Natural numbers are whole numbers excluding zero. Zero is the only whole number which is not a natural number. An array is special if all the elements are natural numbers. Find whether the given array is special or not.

I've tried to use numbers without using `scanf` it worked and functioned as its supposed to function.

Ihis is the code I tried to write:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(){
 int N,special[N] ;
  scanf("%d",&N);

for(N;N>0;N++){  
    if(special[N]>0){
        printf("yes/n");
    }else{
        printf("no/n");
    }
}
    return 0;

}
```

I expect the outout to be yes or no. But the actual output is nothing. There is no output to my code.

Comment: As to the title: you can't. There are an infinite number of natural numbers but computer memory is limited.

Comment: Note: you must declare `int special[N];` _after_ you have read `N`.

Comment: This looks like an infinite loop to me `for(N;N>0;N++)` :)

Comment: Read about integers in C. Thay never have a fractional part.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie but they can be zero or negative ...

Comment: `special[]` is not initialized. `special[i]` can have any integer value. Accessing it can abort your program.

Comment: @Sandy, he says "excluding fractional part"

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You are right, I didn't read thoroughly.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Why do you say that accessing elements of uninitialized array can lead to abort of program?

Comment: @Sandy, because some compilers can place trap values in uninitialized variables. Some compilers can even remove all the code that tries to access uninitalized variables.

Comment: **never** do a _scanf_ or equivalent without checking the returned value to know if valid input(s) was enter or not

Comment: @Sandy Because it's undefined behavior. It can behave in any way. Including aborting the program.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with the code as pointed out in the comments.

One way of what you want to achieve is:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int N;

    int ret = scanf("%d",&N);
    if(1 != ret || N < 0)
        return 1;

    int special[N] ;

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        ret = scanf("%d", &special[i]);
        if(1 != ret)
            return 1;
        if(special[i] == 0){ 
            printf("array not special\n");
            return 1;
        }   
    }   

    printf("special array\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @bruno Absolutely correct. I wrote it this way to keep it simpler to understand. Otherwise there is no need to store values in array

Comment: @bruno Done. Thanks for motivating me.